# How do I get the empty property of a Java BlockingQueue, in order to bind it to some property of a JavaFX element?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, observable

I have a `BlockingQueue` (in particular a `LinkedBlockingQueue`) and would like to obtain the empty property (boolean) of this collection, to be able to bind it to a JavaFX disabled property of a button.

All what I was able to find is the `emptyProperty()` in `ListBinding`, but I am not sure how to proceed beyond this point.

Comment: Why do you have a BlockingQueue?  This task *might* be more easily achieved by removing the concurrent queue and using in-built JavaFX concurrency facilities such as [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: Let me elaborate more on the actual use case. I have a FX Task (let's call it A) and BlockingQueue (call it Q) of FX tasks. A makes use of Q's blocking take() to wait for the next available task, and Q itself is fed from the UI thread when a button is pressed. The way I decided to do it could be naive, but I didn't find a better way... The idea is to finally be able to let the UI buttons be disabled as long as there are elements in the queue, but now that I'm writing this, I figured that this is not correct since the last task would still be working even though it is out of the queue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [`BooleanBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html) with the help of the [`Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) utility class and bind the [`disableProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty--) of a [`Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) to it.

But first, the problem is that you want a `BlockingQueue` and there are no built-in observable queue. Using the code from [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28449809/1743880), we can have a observable queue with:

```
ObservableQueue<String> queue = new ObservableQueue<>(new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
```

and then use it like this:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(queue::isEmpty, queue));
```

You'll find a sample JavaFX application below. This is a very simple application with 3 buttons: one to add an element to the queue, one to remove an element and the third button will change its disable property based on the emptyness of the queue: if the queue is empty, the button will be disabled, otherwise, it will be enabled.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private ObservableQueue<String> queue = new ObservableQueue<>(new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button("Add to queue");
        btn.setOnAction(event -> queue.add("value"));

        Button btn2 = new Button("Remove to queue");
        btn2.setOnAction(event -> queue.remove());

        Button btn3 = new Button("Button");
        btn3.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(queue::isEmpty, queue));

        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn, btn2, btn3);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem here is that a LinkedBlockingQueue is inherently a concurrent structure and JavaFX expects a single threaded application programming model.  Modifying the active scene graph (e.g. disabling a button) off of the JavaFX application thread may cause issues.

Comment: @jewelsea I'll admit I'm also still learning JavaFX. Can something be done to counteract that issue? It seems the issue is with having a `LinkedBlockingQueue` in the first place.

Comment: One could ensure that all calls to the LinkedBlockingQueue execute on the JavaFX application thread, but then a regular Queue could be used, so that wouldn't be a solution.  A special thread safe aware binding could be created, which executes notification of bound changes using [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html); that should be possible, though I haven't seen anybody attempt it to date.  Or a polling task could run in an AnimationTimer or Timeline and set the disabled state of the button appropriately.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks a lot for your input. I'll see if I can update my answer with your information!

Comment: So, I *think* it would work to implement `BlockingQueue` by wrapping an existing `BlockingQueue` implementation, defining a `BooleanProperty emptyQueue;` and in each of the methods that potentially modifies the queue, schedule an update to `emptyQueue` on the FX Application thread. I *think*. It's quite a lot of code, and I'd need to see there's a sensible use case before I put the time into analyzing whether or not the threading is really correct....

Comment: It's probably much simpler (and functionally equivalent to all practical extent) to do as @jewelsea suggests: `new AnimationTimer() { @Override public void handle(long now) { button.setDisable(queue.isEmpty());}}.start();`